# AWS Glue Stored procedure automatic refresh

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have glue script that includes calling a stored procedure, which mostly just refreshing my materialized views based from which table I'm running. Is there any way where its included in the scripts but it will not wait until the SP is finished? My problem is that materialized views takes a while to refresh hence longer time for my glue run.

```
CALL SP_REFRESH;
```

Should I just create a trigger that calls SP?